# Git push is deleting branches

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to git and I fail to understand how can a "git push" command deletes another branch.

There are two branches as you can see below. master and testbranch. These branches were created by two different people. However a "git push" by a user deleted the branch created by another user. Can someone explain how is this possible and what needs to be done to avoid such behavior. For the record, I use GitLab.

**Edit**: Additional info : The use who is pushing has a mirror configured.

[image]

Comment: Git doesn't delete remote branches by default? Normally you'd have to run a command similar to `git push --delete origin remote-branch`

Comment: I wonder if this user might not have some push option in their git config. Try `git config --list` and look for `push` in the output. Are there any push options being configured there?

Comment: For example, if they had a configuration that says "use `--prune`" by default when pushing, that could be the cause.

Comment: @joanis: I just got some more information from the developer. The developer has configured a mirror to the repository. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely going to be a problem. A mirror is meant to be kept in complete sync, so when you push from a mirror, I think it does `--prune` by default. Don't use a mirror unless that's what you want! A mirror is not meant to be used as a sandbox, it's meant to be used for backups or other situations where you want a complete reproduction of a repo somewhere else.

Comment: As an admin , can this not be controlled? Because this is destructive?

Comment: You can put protections on branches that need to be protected, but I'm not sure you can protect arbitrary branches.

Comment: So, have a look at the git push manual: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push . If the clone was a mirror, each push operation will be done with the `--mirror` switch implied, which force pushes everything and prunes locally deleted branches.

Comment: I think your best bet here is education, teach this programmer never to work in a mirror. Hopefully they will only do this mistake once!

Comment: Thnx. But it's a bigger problem as I have no control over what's being deleted. Or may be I don't understand. May be just not allowing my repository to be mirrored would be a good setting. The problem is a new git user could accidentally do things ..

Comment: Backups are my recommendation for handling the general problem of errors by new users.

Comment: FYI: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/588

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into an answer: as you indicated in the chat, the push was done from a mirror, and that is the cause of the problem.

A mirror is meant to be kept in complete sync, so when you push from a mirror, it effectively does `--prune` by default. A mirror is not meant to be used as a sandbox, it's meant to be used for backups or other situations where you want a complete reproduction of a repo somewhere else.

When pushing from a mirror clone, every push operation will be done with the `--mirror` switch implied, which force pushes everything and prunes locally deleted branches. (Ref: [git push manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), look for `--mirror`)

Preventing such problems can be done with:

- branch protection for the important branches (although this won't be practical for all branches);
- user education, making sure users don't treat mirrors as sandboxes;
- regular automated backups, to be able to restore the repo if this happens again.